# how to bring a vertical line in table and content go in second line in same cell when using tabularx packkage

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I want to bring a vertical line in table here is the code I have.
This is a thesis which uses a template which can be seen  [here](https://github.com/kiotie32/original-template/blob/master/thesis.tex) with full source code.
In my latex implementation of table

```
\documentclass[twoside,mtp]{iiitg}

\usepackage{makecell,tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}


    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|@{} X | @{}X | @{}X |}
    \hline       
    \thead{Algorithm}   & \thead{Pros}  & \thead{Cons} \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{1. K Nearest Neighbour:  K-NN }   & Very easy to understand 
    Good for creating models that include non standard data types such as
    text             & Large Storage requirements
    Computationally Expensive
    Sensitive to the choice of the similarity function for comparing instances             \\ \hline
    Local Outlier Factor(LOF)  & 3             & 5             \\ \hline
    1               & 3             & 5             \\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{Anomaly Detection Algorithms comparison}
        \label{tab:my_label}
    \end{table}
```

[image: algorithm comparison]
I want KNN to go in 2nd rows in the same cell in the above implementation that is not happening and vertical lines to make a boundary.

Comment: Remove the `\multirow` around "1. K Nearest Neighbour:  K-NN". Also remove all three `@{}` if you want vertical lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with the options in square brackets to get desired result of spacing etc
`[label={}, wide = 0pt, leftmargin = *, nosep, itemsep = 0pt, before = \vspace*{\baselineskip}, after =\vspace*{\baselineskip} ]`

-- the `label={}` eliminates label 1,2 --- and so on 
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}





\usepackage{makecell,tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}

\begin{document}


    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X |X | X |}
    \hline       
    \thead{Algorithm}   & \thead{Pros}  & \thead{Cons} \\ \hline
    \begin{enumerate}[label={}, wide = 0pt, leftmargin = *, nosep, itemsep = 0pt, before = \vspace*{\baselineskip}, after =\vspace*{\baselineskip} ]
\item K Nearest Neighbour
\item K-NN
    \end{enumerate}   & 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Very easy to understand 
    \item Good for creating models that include non standard data types such as
    text
\end{enumerate}             &
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Large Storage requirements
\item Computationally Expensive
\item Sensitive to the choice of the similarity function for comparing instances
\end{enumerate}             \\ \hline

        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{Anomaly Detection Algorithms comparison}
        \label{tab:my_label}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ok thanks and this table is going to several pages then what should be included in the \begin{tabular} section I tried \begin{longtable} but that did not help. Also give a link that can help me understand more about label that you used in your code.

Comment: please reaad the documentation on latex package `enumitem` --google search-- for tables in general read wikibooks -- `https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables`

Comment: ok did that but seems I messed up with code some where , I have opened a new question here please have a look https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542677/how-to-enumerate-objects-in-xltabular-and-long-table

Comment: is there an advantage in xtabular -- i have used tabularx --

Comment: I do not know about tabularx the only reason I use xltabular  is because my tables became very long and became difficult for me to keep them on same page or even have a page break and then continue the table on next page. I tried a lot of things nothing worked then some one suggested on my question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542652/creating-a-very-long-table-and-keeping-it-on-same-page#comment1370634_542652 to use xltabular. That worked so  I am using it.

Comment: ok go ahead -- please upvote and accept the answer if you found it helpful