# creating a very long table and keeping it on same page

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am creating a long table below the following text

The text is "Initially, we will use all features. "

but when I create the table then

```
\begin{table} [h!]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l X @{}} 

duration & length (number of seconds) of the connection \\
src_bytes & number of data bytes from source to destination \\
dst_bytes & number of data bytes from destination to source     \\
land & 1 if connection is from/to the same host/port; 0 otherwise \\
wrong_fragment &number of ``wrong'' fragments   \\
urgent & number of urgent packets   \\
hot & number of ``hot'' indicators  \\
num_failed_logins & number of failed login attempts \\
logged_in & 1 if successfully logged in; 0 otherwise \\
num_compromised & number of ``compromised'' conditions  \\
root_shell & 1 if root shell is obtained; 0 otherwise   \\
su_attempted & 1 if ``su root'' command attempted; 0 otherwise  \\
num_root & number of ``root'' accesses  \\
num_file_creations & number of file creation operations     \\
num_shells & number of shell prompts    \\
num_access_files & number of operations on access control files     \\
num_outbound_cmds & number of outbound commands in an ftp session   \\
is_host_login & 1 if the login belongs to the ``hot'' list; 0 otherwise     \\
is_guest_login & 1 if the login is a ``guest''login; 0 otherwise     \\
count & number of connections to the same host as the current connection in the past two seconds    \\
srv_count & number of connections to the same service as the current connection in the past two seconds     \\
serror_rate & \% of connections that have ``SYN'' errors \\
srv_serror_rate & \% of connections that have ``SYN'' errors    \\
rerror_rate & \% of connections that have ``REJ'' errors    \\
same_srv_rate & \\
diff_srv_rate & \\
srv_diff_host_rate & \\
dst_host_count & \\
dst_host_srv_count & \\
dst_host_same_srv_rate & \\
dst_host_diff_srv_rate & \\
dst_host_same_src_port_rate & \\
dst_host_srv_diff_host_rate & \\
dst_host_serror_rate & \\
dst_host_srv_serror_rate & \\
dst_host_rerror_rate & \\
dst_host_srv_rerror_rate & \\

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

every thing is blank below text and table is generated on next page. You can see following screenshot
[image: blank after text]
so how can I get rid of this situation. The table content may span upto next page or more also in my case.
I tried

```
\begin{longtable} [h!]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l X @{}} 

\end{tabularx}
\end{longtable}
```

but that also did not helped. I am using a template given by department which you can see [here](https://github.com/kiotie32/original-template)

Comment: Try putting `\vspace*{-10em}` before `table` environment and see whether it works for you. Probably, you would need to change the value of negative space.

Comment: no that did not helped I tried putting it

Comment: I'd recommend decreasing the space till you see any result. For example `-50em`

Comment: just have a tabularx and remove the table environment, the only reason to use table is to allow the table to be moved.

Comment: ou can't put on one page a table, which height than text height or the height of available space on page. There exist some trick as reduce `\arraystreatch` (for example `\renewcommand\arraystreatch{0.84}`) or  use smaller font size (for example `\small`, eventually `\footnotesize}`) . One possibilities is to split table into two parts or use `longtable` that it can be placed on the two pages. You can't expect that elephant can be put in lady suitcase ....

Comment: but please always provide a complete small test document so people can test answers. Currently for example you are asking people to make the table fit a page without saying how big the page is. A test file would clarify that....

Comment: the page is a4 size or I could not understand what you wanted to know.

Comment: If you want the table to start on the same page as the text and want to allow a pagebreak if necessary, Remove the `table` environment and replace `tabularx` with `xltabular`. You will also need the `xltabular` package for that. Also replace `_` by `\_`.

Comment: @leandriis thanks your solution worked perfectly.