# how to enumerate objects in xltabular and long table

Tags: tables, longtable, xltabular

I am using a template given by department which has 
thesis.tex file its content which I feel relevant are here

```
    \documentclass[twoside,mtp]{iiitg}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \rightmark}
  \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textbf{\thepage}}
  \fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
  \fancyfoot{}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername \ \thechapter \ \ #1}{}}
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \ \ #1}}
\tableofcontents

 \clearemptydoublepage

 % Make the list of figures
 \listoffigures
 \clearemptydoublepage

 % Make the list of tables
 \listoftables
 \clearemptydoublepage

%\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols and Abbreviation}
%\include{files/symb_b}
%\include{files/symb_b1}
%\clearemptydoublepage

\onehalfspace

 % Start regular page counting at page 1
\mainmatter
\addtolength{\parskip}{0.05\baselineskip}

\abovedisplayskip=13pt
\belowdisplayskip=13pt

\clearemptydoublepage
\input{texfiles/chapter1}
\clearemptydoublepage
\input{texfiles/chapter2}
\clearemptydoublepage
\input{texfiles/chapter3}
\clearemptydoublepage
\input{texfiles/chapter4}
\clearemptydoublepage
\input{texfiles/conclusion}
\clearemptydoublepage
```

and here in chapter2 I am making the table which is long and it does not fit in single page due to text above it.
So I wrote it in following way

```
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} l X @{} X @{} X} 
\hline       
\thead{Algorithm}   & \thead{Pros}  & \thead{Cons} \\ \hline
\begin{enumerate}[label={}, wide = 0pt, leftmargin = *, nosep, itemsep = 0pt, before = \vspace*{\baselineskip}, after =\vspace*{\baselineskip} ]
\item K Nearest Neighbour
\item K-NN
    \end{enumerate}   & \begin{enumerate}
    \item Very easy to understand 
    \item Good for creating models that include non standard data types such as
    text
\end{enumerate}       & Large Storage requirements
Computationally Expensive
Sensitive to the choice of the similarity function for comparing instances             \\ \hline
Local Outlier Factor(LOF)  & Well-known and good algorithm
for local anomaly detection
             & Only relies on its direct neighborhood .\newline Perform poorly on data sets with global anomalies. \\ \hline
K Means       & Low Complexity \newline Very easy to implement & Each cluster has pretty equal number of observations \newline Necessity of specifying K \newline Only work with numerical data \\ \hline
Support Vector Machine (SVM) & Find the best separation hyper-plane.Deal with very high dimensional data.\newline 
Can learn very elaborate concepts.
Work very well         & Require both positive and negative examples. Require lots of memory.\newline Some numerical stability problems.Need to select a good kernel function   \\ \hline
Neural networks based anomaly detection & Learns and does not need to be reprogrammed.\newline Can be implemented in any application  &    Needs training to operate \newline Requires high processing time for large neural networks \newline The architecture needs to be emulated          \\ \hline
    \caption{Anomaly Detection Algorithms comparison}
    \label{tab:algorithm_comp}
    \end{xltabular}
```

The generated table looks as below
[image: generated table]
I think this is having some error. I am not clear what is the error due to the appearance.
What could possibly be this error in above implementation?

Comment: Did you add the enumitem package to the preamble?

Comment: Also remove the @{} to prevent the overlapping of text. See for example the non existant horizontal space between "local" and "neighborhood" in the second row.

Comment: Please also explain why you declare 4 columns but only use 3. Remove the last X.

Comment: I think there are only three columns declared if you see I have put `\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} l X @{} X @{} X} ` only 3 X are there. As per my understanding three X means 3 columns, I am not clear with what @{} does. I just added it I don't remember where I read it.

Comment: You definitely declared a total of 4 columns: 3 X type ones and 1 l type one.

Comment: Is is purposely that the enumerate in the second column has a vertical space above?

Comment: no it has accidentally generated these are the errors due to which I posted the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was the `l` column where you tried to put multiple paragraph. I redefined that as a left aligned x-column. If you need different column width, look into the tabularx-documentation regarding using `\hsize`.

I also defined the lacking `\thead` command, and changed all `\hline`s to booktabs-rules.

It is som awful line breaks, but that is fixable.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular, booktabs, enumitem}
\usepackage{babel}

\newcommand{\thead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X X X @{}} 
\caption{Anomaly Detection Algorithms comparison\label{tab:algorithm_comp}}\\

\toprule      
\thead{Algorithm}   & \thead{Pros}  & \thead{Cons} \\ \midrule
\begin{enumerate}%
[label={}, wide = 0pt, leftmargin = *, nosep, itemsep = 0pt, before = \vspace*{\baselineskip}, after =\vspace*{\baselineskip} ]
\item K Nearest Neighbour
\item K-NN
\end{enumerate}   & \begin{enumerate}
    \item Very easy to understand 
    \item Good for creating models that include non standard data types such as
    text
\end{enumerate}       & Large Storage requirements
Computationally Expensive
Sensitive to the choice of the similarity function for comparing instances             \\ \midrule
Local Outlier Factor(LOF)  & Well-known and good algorithm
for local anomaly detection
             & Only relies on its direct neighborhood .\newline Perform poorly on data sets with global anomalies. \\ \midrule
K Means       & Low Complexity \newline Very easy to implement & Each cluster has pretty equal number of observations \newline Necessity of specifying K \newline Only work with numerical data \\ \midrule
Support Vector Machine (SVM) & Find the best separation hyper-plane.Deal with very high dimensional data.\newline 
Can learn very elaborate concepts.
Work very well         & Require both positive and negative examples. Require lots of memory.\newline Some numerical stability problems.Need to select a good kernel function   \\ \midrule
Neural networks based anomaly detection & Learns and does not need to be reprogrammed.\newline Can be implemented in any application  &    Needs training to operate \newline Requires high processing time for large neural networks \newline The architecture needs to be emulated          \\ \bottomrule

    \end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion. I have changed the horizontal alignment in the columns from justified to left aligned in order to prevent large blank space between words. Since the first column contains less text than the second and third, I have decreased the column width of the first column in comparison to the other columns. I order to provide more structure, I have used a newly defined `tabitem` environment for the entries in the "Pros"  and "Cons"  columns. In the following MWE, I have also included another example that only needs two columns:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular, booktabs, enumitem}

\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem]{wide=0pt, nosep, leftmargin= * ,label=\textendash,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}


\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.85cm}LL @{}}
\caption{Anomaly Detection Algorithms comparison\label{tab:algorithm_comp}}\\ 
\toprule      
\thead{Algorithm}   & \thead{Pros}  & \thead{Cons} \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule      
\thead{Algorithm}   & \thead{Pros}  & \thead{Cons} \\ 
\midrule
\endhead
K Nearest Neighbour K-NN
    & \begin{tabitem}
      \item Very easy to understand 
      \item Good for creating models that include non standard data types such as text
      \end{tabitem}       
          & \begin{tabitem} 
            \item Large Storage requirements 
            \item Computationally Expensive 
            \item Sensitive to the choice of the similarity function for comparing instances 
            \end{tabitem}            \\ 
\midrule
Local Outlier Factor (LOF)  
    & \begin{tabitem}
      \item Well-known and good algorithm for local anomaly detection
      \end{tabitem}
        &  \begin{tabitem} 
           \item Only relies on its direct neighborhood.
           \item Perform poorly on data sets with global anomalies. 
           \end{tabitem}\\ 
\midrule
K Means       
    & \begin{tabitem}
      \item Low Complexity 
      \item Very easy to implement 
      \end{tabitem}
          & \begin{tabitem}
            \item Each cluster has pretty equal number of observations 
            \item Necessity of specifying K 
            \item Only work with numerical data
            \end{tabitem} \\ 
\midrule
Support Vector Machine (SVM) 
    & \begin{tabitem}
      \item Find the best separation hyper-plane. 
      \item Deal with very high dimensional data.
      \item Can learn very elaborate concepts.
      \item Work very well
      \end{tabitem}        
          & \begin{tabitem}
            \item Require both positive and negative examples. 
            \item Require lots of memory.
            \item Some numerical stability problems.
            \item Need to select a good kernel function
            \end{tabitem}   \\ 
\midrule
Neural networks based anomaly detection 
    & \begin{tabitem}
      \item Learns and does not need to be reprogrammed
      \item Can be implemented in any application 
      \end{tabitem} 
          & \begin{tabitem}
            \item Needs training to operate 
            \item Requires high processing time for large neural networks 
            \item The architecture needs to be emulated 
            \end{tabitem}\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{xltabular}

%\pagebreak

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{LL @{}}
\caption{Anomaly Detection Algorithms comparison\label{tab:algorithm_comp}}\\ 
\toprule      
    Pros  & Cons \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule      
    \thead{Pros}  & \thead{Cons} \\ 
\midrule
\endhead
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\itshape K Nearest Neighbour K-NN}\\*
     \begin{tabitem}
     \item Very easy to understand 
     \item Good for creating models that include non standard data types such as text
      \end{tabitem}       
          & \begin{tabitem} 
            \item Large Storage requirements 
            \item Computationally Expensive 
            \item Sensitive to the choice of the similarity function for comparing instances 
            \end{tabitem}            \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\itshape Local Outlier Factor (LOF)}\\*  
      \begin{tabitem}
      \item Well-known and good algorithm for local anomaly detection
      \end{tabitem}
        &  \begin{tabitem} 
           \item Only relies on its direct neighborhood.
           \item Perform poorly on data sets with global anomalies. 
           \end{tabitem}\\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\itshape K Means}\\*      
      \begin{tabitem}
      \item Low Complexity 
      \item Very easy to implement 
      \end{tabitem}
          & \begin{tabitem}
            \item Each cluster has pretty equal number of observations 
            \item Necessity of specifying K 
            \item Only work with numerical data
            \end{tabitem} \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\itshape Support Vector Machine (SVM)}\\*
      \begin{tabitem}
      \item Find the best separation hyper-plane. 
      \item Deal with very high dimensional data.
      \item Can learn very elaborate concepts.
      \item Work very well
      \end{tabitem}        
          & \begin{tabitem}
            \item Require both positive and negative examples. 
            \item Require lots of memory.
            \item Some numerical stability problems.
            \item Need to select a good kernel function
            \end{tabitem}   \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\itshape Neural networks based anomaly detection}\\ 
      \begin{tabitem}
      \item Learns and does not need to be reprogrammed
      \item Can be implemented in any application 
      \end{tabitem} 
          & \begin{tabitem}
            \item Needs training to operate 
            \item Requires high processing time for large neural networks 
            \item The architecture needs to be emulated 
            \end{tabitem}\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

An entirely different approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{proconlist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[proconlist]{label=+.,leftmargin=*, nosep}

\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\captionof{table}{Pros (+) and Cons (--) of Different Anomaly Detection Algorithms \label{tab:algorithm_comp}} 
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
  \item K Nearest Neighbour K-NN
    \begin{proconlist}
        \item[+]  Very easy to understand 
        \item[+]  Good for creating models that include non standard data types such as text
        \item[--] Large Storage requirements 
        \item[--] Computationally Expensive 
        \item[--] Sensitive to the choice of the similarity function for comparing instances 
    \end{proconlist}       
  \item Local Outlier Factor (LOF)  
    \begin{proconlist}
        \item[+]  Well-known and good algorithm for local anomaly detection
        \item[--] Only relies on its direct neighborhood.
        \item[--] Perform poorly on data sets with global anomalies. 
    \end{proconlist} 
  \item K Means       
    \begin{proconlist}
        \item[+]  Low Complexity 
        \item[+]  Very easy to implement 
        \item[--]  Each cluster has pretty equal number of observations 
        \item[--]  Necessity of specifying K 
        \item[--]  Only work with numerical data
    \end{proconlist} 
  \item Support Vector Machine (SVM) 
    \begin{proconlist}
        \item[+] Find the best separation hyper-plane. 
        \item[+] Deal with very high dimensional data.
        \item[+] Can learn very elaborate concepts.
        \item[+] Work very well
        \item[--] Require both positive and negative examples. 
        \item[--] Require lots of memory.
        \item[--] Some numerical stability problems.
        \item[--] Need to select a good kernel function
    \end{proconlist} 
  \item Neural networks based anomaly detection 
    \begin{proconlist}
        \item[+] Learns and does not need to be reprogrammed
        \item[+] Can be implemented in any application 
        \item[--] Needs training to operate 
        \item[--] Requires high processing time for large neural networks 
        \item[--] The architecture needs to be emulated 
    \end{proconlist} 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: wow thiis also great.Actually I am not very clear with use of xltabular and the kind of tables you produced here. I would say as a new comer I am able to understand the syntax of tabular and how it generates tables. I practised a lot in past 2 days just for making sample tables at my end. But what you wrote here I could not even think. 
So I just want to know if you have some good resource like video or link which can easily explain in easy words using xtabular or what you mentioned here. I am reading a lot of tutorials these days for tables and how to make them beautiful.

Comment: @koeradoera: I unfortumately can not recommend good learning resources. If you have a specific question about a part of the code I wrote, please feel free to ask.